# How to scan jsx attributes in webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am developing my first webpack plugin. I need to scan all element attributes.

For example:

```
<div bg={'red'}></div>
```

In all code I want to find "bg" attribute

I'm assuming the "parser" hook can do that, but the documentation doesn't say how to scan attributes in jsx

```
apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.normalModuleFactory.tap('myWebpackPlugin', (factory) => {
        factory.hooks.parser
            .for('javascript/auto')
            .tap('myWebpackPlugin', (parser, options) => {



            });
    });
}
```

help me please